# How to read .rc extension file in java

Tags: java

I want to read .rc file in java and store its content in hashmap. 
.rc ext files are the resource files used in C/C++ and I want to develop the application in java.
Please help. Thanks in Advance.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        try                                                                                                                                     
        {    
            JobConf job = new JobConf(new Configuration(), Application.class);
            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(job);                                                                                         
            FileStatus [] fileStatuses = fs.listStatus(new Path("C:/Users/Desktop/fold/"));                               
            LongWritable key = new LongWritable();                                                                                       
            BytesRefArrayWritable value = new BytesRefArrayWritable();                                                                   
            int counter = 1;                                                                                                             
            for (int i = 0; i < fileStatuses.length; i++)                                                                                
            {                                                                                                                            
                FileStatus fileStatus = fileStatuses[i];                                                                                 
                if (!fileStatus.isDir())                                                                                                 
                {                                                                                                                        
                    System.out.println("File: " + fileStatus);                                                                           
                    FileSplit split = new FileSplit(fileStatus.getPath(), 0, fileStatus.getLen(), job);                                  
                    RCFileRecordReader reader = new RCFileRecordReader(job, split);                                                      
                    while (reader.next(key, value))                                                                                      
                    {                                                                                                                    
                        System.out.println("Getting row " + counter);                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                        counter++;                                                                                                       
                    }                                                                                                                    
                }                                                                                                                        
            }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        }                                                                                                                                
        catch (IOException e)                                                                                                            
        {                                                                                                                                
            throw new Error(e);                                                                                                          
        }
    }
```

It gave me exception :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: java.io.IOException:
>   file:/C:/Users/Desktop/fold/xyz.rc not a RCFile and has magic of I01
>     at Application.main(Application.java:119) Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: file:/C:/Users/Desktop/fold/xyz.rc not a RCFile
>   and has magic of I01  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.RCFile$Reader.init(RCFile.java:1269)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.RCFile$Reader.(RCFile.java:1154)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.RCFile$Reader.(RCFile.java:1133)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.RCFileRecordReader.(RCFileRecordReader.java:102)
>     at Application.main(Application.java:106)

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read in a RCFile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25416114/how-to-read-in-a-rcfile)

Comment: I checked the question what you have mentioned and Im not getting possible value for JobConf job

Answer (score 0):

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Desktop/fold/xyz.rc");
try {
    String str = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
    System.out.println(str);
} finally {
    inputStream.close();
}
```